# Impersonation and Activator.CreateInstance() on remote machine

Tags: c#, com, impersonation

I'm using [SimpleImpersonation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleImpersonation/) throughout my C# application to simplify the use of the Win32 LogonUser function. This works fine in all cases so far, except this particular one where I need to create a COM object instance on a remote machine with different credentials.

Is there any way to wrap a call to `Activator.CreateInstance()` against a remote machine with alternate credentials? No matter which value for `LogonType` I pass, I get Access Denied (0x80070005).

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, username, password, LogonType.Interactive))
{
    try
    {
        Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", hostname, true);
        var comobj = Activator.CreateInstance(t); // <== throws UnauthorizedAccessException
        UpdateSession session = (UpdateSession) comobj;
        IUpdateSearcher updateSearcher = session.CreateUpdateSearcher();

        var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();

                ...
```

For comparison, this works fine from Powershell if I start the prompt as a different user:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $updatesession = [activator]::CreateInstance([type]::GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Session", $hostname))
```

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No I don't think it's possible